# Minecraft server, Water Pouring Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm playing on my own server with Minecraft 1.1 and have installed Industrialcraft 1.62 and Buildcraft 2.21 and the required ModLoader MP 1.1 v2.1 Server and minecraftforge server 1.3.

I have a problem where I can pour water into tanks, but if I try to place it anywhere else like on dirt, stone, etc. appears for half a second and then disappears. If I click the water bucket in the inventory, the water disappears and an empty bucket remains.

Comment: Since I have never used those mods I can not say this specifically as an answer, but when something appears for a split second then disappears, it usually means that the Server has rejected the action that the player did. You should be able to check the server log to see what happened I would think.

Comment: Do you really have a water bucket?  Try rejoining the world.

Answer (score 1):

Mods

1. Better than wolves,
2. Better than BuildCraft,
3. BuildCraft

After installing buildcraft & better than build craft Water would disapear after dropping.

I put BTBConfig.txt in .minecraft folder & disabled hardcore bucket mode.
This is the settings that work now. Hope it helps you.

```
// config settings

// set the following to 1 to disable "hardcore buckets" mode.
// This setting overrides the one found in the BTWConfig file

btbDisableHardcoreBuckets=1

// Block IDs    

btbSpoutID=185

// Item IDs

// Entity IDs
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of servers use tools to remove all player placed water outside of certain areas to prevent 1) Malicious flooding, 2) performance hits from water calculations.

I notice it is your own server, so perhaps minecraftforge server has a default setting that does this that you haven't disabled?

Comment: Any Idea how I can find and change that default setting?

Comment: @Hamalamah, im afraid not as I dont use the mod myself. I just suggested it as a possibility because I have heard of this behaviour before. I would suggest reading the mod page on minecraft forum.